# How to create a recursive zipWith function in Haskell?

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion

So far I have:

```
miZipWith f [] [] = []
miZipWith f (x:xs) [] = []
miZipWith f [] (y:ys) = []
miZipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f y: miZipWith f xs ys

----miZipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x : f y : miZipWith f xs ys
```

But this only "zips" the function f with the second list. How do I include the first list too?

```
*Main> miZipWith (*2) [1,2,3,4] [5,6,1]
[10,12,2]
```

Comment: What you're missing is that the type of `f` is `(a -> b -> c)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `zipWith` function goes like this:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith f xs ys
zipWith _ _ _ = []
```

Your assumption is that the function `f` takes only one argument, but it in fact takes two (the head of both lists).

Comment: Technically I know that, but it won't compile (even after defining miZipWith with zipWith's definition.).

Comment: <interactive>:263:1:
    Could not deduce (Num (b0 -> c))
      arising from the ambiguity check for ‘it’
    from the context (Num (b -> c), Num b)
      bound by the inferred type for ‘it’: (Num (b -> c), Num b) => [c]
      at <interactive>:263:1-32
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    When checking that ‘it’
      has the inferred type ‘forall b c. (Num (b -> c), Num b) => [c]’
    Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous

Comment: `miZipWith (*2) [1,2,3,4] [5,6,1]` should now be `miZipWith (*) [1,2,3,4] [5,6,1]`